# Convert Pandas Dataframe to Dictionary with Tuple Keys for Ternary plot

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I am plotting ternary diagrams with [python-ternary](https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary)

My data is in a pandas dataframe. I need to convert it to a dictionary mapping (i, j)  to a float as input for the `heatmap` function in ternary.

My dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
   i  j  value
0  1  2      7
1  3  4      8
2  5  6      9
```

I need to make a dictionary like this:

```
{(1, 2): 7, (5, 6): 9, (3, 4): 8}
```

My current workaround is a brute force loop that is very slow:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'i': [1, 3, 5], 'j': [2, 4, 6], 'value': [7, 8, 9]})
data = dict()

for k in range(0, len(df)):
    data[(df.iloc[k]['i'],df.iloc[k]['j'])] = \
        df.iloc[k]['value']
```

Please, could someone help me with a faster or more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index(['i','j'])['value'].to_dict()
```

Alternative with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {(a,b):c for a,b,c in zip(df['i'], df['j'], df['value'])}
```

---

```
print (d)
{(1, 2): 7, (3, 4): 8, (5, 6): 9}
```

Comment: @Charles Maupou - Thank you.